# Problem While Installing zbarlight ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, visual-c++

I'm trying to install the zbarlight via "pip install" in the CMC and I'm receiving this error in return:

```
C:\Users\Usuário>pip install zbarlight
Collecting zbarlight
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3d/ee/de1466b1170e347d185dc0c3f75c1100fab03bb2a9544f142bb5bbccd182/zbarlight-2.3.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in c:\users\usuário\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from zbarlight) (6.1.0)
Installing collected packages: zbarlight
  Running setup.py install for zbarlight ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\usuário\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\USURIO~2\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-qzmg3wl5\\zbarlight\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\USURIO~2\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-qzmg3wl5\\zbarlight\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\USURIO~2\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-obgwez3y\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: C:\Users\USURIO~2\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qzmg3wl5\zbarlight\
    Complete output (51 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\zbarlight
    copying src\zbarlight\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\zbarlight
    running egg_info
    writing src\zbarlight.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to src\zbarlight.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing requirements to src\zbarlight.egg-info\requires.txt
    writing top-level names to src\zbarlight.egg-info\top_level.txt
    reading manifest file 'src\zbarlight.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'tests'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.py[cod]' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '__pycache__' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'Makefile'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'requirements-dev.txt'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'tox.ini'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'run.py'
    writing manifest file 'src\zbarlight.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    copying src\zbarlight\_zbarlight.c -> build\lib.win32-3.7\zbarlight
    running build_ext
    building 'zbarlight._zbarlight' extension
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\src
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\src\zbarlight
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT -Ic:\users\usuário\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include -Ic:\users\usuário\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc/zbarlight/_zbarlight.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.7\Release\src/zbarlight/_zbarlight.obj -std=c99
    cl : Linha de comando warning D9002 : ignorando op‡Æo desconhecida '-std=c99'
    _zbarlight.c
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\bin\HostX86\x86\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /nodefaultlib:libucrt.lib ucrt.lib /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:c:\users\usuário\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\libs /LIBPATH:c:\users\usuário\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\PCbuild\win32 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\ATLMFC\lib\x86" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\lib\x86" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\x86" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x86" zbar.lib /EXPORT:PyInit__zbarlight build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\src/zbarlight/_zbarlight.obj /OUT:build\lib.win32-3.7\zbarlight\_zbarlight.cp37-win32.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\src/zbarlight\_zbarlight.cp37-win32.lib
       Criando biblioteca build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\src/zbarlight\_zbarlight.cp37-win32.lib e objeto build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\src/zbarlight\_zbarlight.cp37-win32.exp
    _zbarlight.obj : error LNK2001: símbolos externos indefinidos _zbar_image_set_data
    _zbarlight.obj : error LNK2001: símbolos externos indefinidos _zbar_image_destroy
    _zbarlight.obj : error LNK2001: símbolos externos indefinidos _zbar_symbol_get_data
    _zbarlight.obj : error LNK2001: símbolos externos indefinidos _zbar_image_create
    _zbarlight.obj : error LNK2001: símbolos externos indefinidos _zbar_image_scanner_set_config
    _zbarlight.obj : error LNK2001: símbolos externos indefinidos _zbar_image_scanner_create
    _zbarlight.obj : error LNK2001: símbolos externos indefinidos _zbar_image_scanner_destroy
    _zbarlight.obj : error LNK2001: símbolos externos indefinidos _zbar_symbol_next
    _zbarlight.obj : error LNK2001: símbolos externos indefinidos _zbar_image_set_format
    _zbarlight.obj : error LNK2001: símbolos externos indefinidos _zbar_symbol_get_data_length
    _zbarlight.obj : error LNK2001: símbolos externos indefinidos _zbar_image_set_size
    _zbarlight.obj : error LNK2001: símbolos externos indefinidos _zbar_image_first_symbol
    _zbarlight.obj : error LNK2001: símbolos externos indefinidos _zbar_scan_image
    build\lib.win32-3.7\zbarlight\_zbarlight.cp37-win32.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 13 externo não resolvidos
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.23.28105\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1120
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\usuário\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\USURIO~2\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-qzmg3wl5\\zbarlight\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\USURIO~2\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-qzmg3wl5\\zbarlight\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\USURIO~2\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-obgwez3y\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

I already installed the Microsoft Visual C++ (the last version of it), already had pasted the bar.h and zbar.lib in their correct folders and I'm still getting errors during the zbarlight installation, this is the message I'm receiving and don't know what else to do. Does anyone know a solution for this problem?